# Java split method

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to split an inputted number such as (123) 456-7890.

```
 String [] split = s.split(delimiters);
```

I have been searching the web for ways of delimiting the area code inside the set of the parentheses but I haven't found anything that works for my case. I do not know if the array is messing up with it printing either. The array is not required but I did not know what else to do since it is required to use the split method.

Comment: Your first splitted element is `(123`, so then you do `System.out.println("(" + NumberTokens[0] + ")")` you get two braces. Either add `(` to delimeters and start from element 1 or just print without `"("`

Comment: I need to make sure 123 is a token/element though and not (123.

Comment: Just remove all non-digit characters (simple regex) and process your number any way you like: `System.out.println("123) 456-7890".replaceAll("\\D", ""));`

Comment: Why did you remove all the details from your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String phoneNumber = "(123)-456-7890";
        String pattern = "\\((\\d+)\\)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(phoneNumber);
        if (m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2) + " " + m.group(3));
     }
}
```

You can try it [here](http://goo.gl/u4B5uI).

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question - as the OP requires the use of the `split` method. Also the phone number does not have a hyphen after the parenthesis: i is `"(123) 456-7890"` not `"(123)-456-7890"`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you could use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) like `(XXX) XXX-XXXX` where `X` is a digit. You can also use `{n}` to require `n` occurences. You group with `()`. Something like,

```
String str = "(123) 456-7890";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d{3})\\) (\\d{3})-(\\d{4})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    String areaCode = m.group(1);
    String first3digits = m.group(2);
    String last4digits = m.group(3);
    System.out.printf("(%s) %s-%s%n", areaCode, first3digits,
            last4digits);
}
```

Gives your requested output of

```
(123) 456-7890
```

**or**, if you must use `split` you might first remove the `(` and `)` with a call to `replaceAll` and something like

```
String str = "(123) 456-7890";
String[] arr = str.replaceAll("[()]", "").split("[ -]");
System.out.printf("(%s) %s-%s%n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

which also gives your requested output of

```
(123) 456-7890
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question - as the OP requires the use of the `split` method.

Comment: you can split on the `()` so you don't need to replace them.

Comment: @igreen True, but you get two empty `String`(s) in the array. With my approach you do not.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the split method:

```
String s= "(123) 456-7890"
String[] split = s.split("[()-]");
System.out.println("(" + split[1] + ")" + split[2] + "-" + split[3]);
```

Comment: You don't need the \\ and a + after the pattern allows back-to-back delimiters to be captured.

Comment: The hyphen has special meaning between the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
    String s= "(123) 456-7890";
    String[] parts = s.split("[()\\- ]");
    System.out.println("(" + parts[1] + ") " + parts[3] + "-" + parts[4]);
```